# prevent vim from backupping large files

Tags: vim, backup

After configuring `:set backupdir=...`, anytime I save a file Vim lovely backups it in the chosen backup directory.

My current problem is that backup directory size grows fast.

Is there a way to tell Vim to not backup files when file-size is above, say, 10Mb?

If no, can we set a cap to the backup directory size (after which Vim can safely delete older backups)?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current file name by:

```
expand(@%)
```

You can get the size of a file by:

```
getfsize()
```

You can add file you don't want to backup to the `backupskip`  by:

```
set bsk +=yourFile
```

You can weave them together, check if the size > your threshold then skip the file, to make this happen automatically, you may want to create an `autocommand`.